# FOV in perspective projection

Tags: graphics

Perspective projection can either be described by distance from viewing plane and angle (FOV) , or by distance from image plane and extents of image plane( Left, Right, Top , Bottom). My question is given extents of viewing (image) plane and distance from image plane, how to calculate the corresponding FOV?

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenGL FAQ](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) has a section (9.085) that describes this:

```
fov*0.5 = arctan ((top-bottom)*0.5 / near)
```

or

```
fov = 2.0 * arctan ((top-bottom)*0.5 / near)
```

Note that the result will be in radians rather than degrees.